# How to pass form data from client to server in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to make an e-commerce app which lets users buy items after adding them to a cart. However, I have been trying to pass data from the client to the server (e.g. total cost of the items in cart, list of the items in the cart) so that the server can handle the billing, and I cant seem to find a way to do so. What would be the best practice for handling such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way you can pass data into server use `Meteor.methods` and call it on the client. for more information you can see [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html)
for example you defined a `method` on the server and call it on the client.

Comment: so if im not mistaken the way I would do this is to pass the data into the method as an argument and then define the variables within the server based on the arguments i pass in?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code sample I use to get form data passed to a meteor method.

```
'submit #payment-form': function (event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = {};
    instance.findAll('input').forEach(function (input) {
            formData[input.id] = input.value;
    });
    Meteor.call('someMethod', formData, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```